# If clients broadcast SSID's anyway, does it make a difference if AP is hidden or not?

Tags: wifi

In this link, it is explained why a client sends probes to a hidden network: [link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/97537/why-do-phones-send-wifi-probes)
And here it states that clients will send probes for any network to save battery: [link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/152007/why-do-wifi-devices-broadcast)

So does it make a difference from a privacy perspective if clients are broadcasting the SSID anyway?

Because hiding it would help against wardrivers and google pinning the SSID to a location.

Comment: Hidden SSID is more of an UX feature than a security one. It's good to be able to hide dozens of internal/management SSIDs in order to present a clean UI to your customers with only the networks that are relevant to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we agree that hiding the SSID is not a security feature. But it can be handy sometimes because the attacker **needs at least one connected client** to a hidden network to send de-auth and get the SSID.

Most important, hiding the SSID might affect client's privacy. Because the client is **broadcasting** a **trusted network SSID**, so a rogue AP can be set by an attacker, and then he might be able to set mitm. "*only if the network is set to open auth*"

Check [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/75832/28790) answer for more,